# Cannot change global variable value in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am changing a **global variable** value inside a method and trying to return it later .

**In FetchData.kt ( The called class )**

```
var homeFeed: HomeFeed? = null     // the variable that needs to be changed 

fun execute() {


    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val url =
        "..."
    val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()

    val res = client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {

            e.printStackTrace()

        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {

            val ch = response?.body?.string()

            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            homeFeed= gson.fromJson(ch, HomeFeed::class.java)  // where the change happens

        }

    })

}

   fun GetData(): HomeFeed? {

       return homeFeed
   }
```

**In MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

   btn.setOnClickListener {

      val  destination = "destination"

      val places = FetchData(destination)

      places.execute()
      val data = places.GetData()
   }
}
```

The problem is that a **Null** value is assigned to "data" variable in **MainActivity** as if the returned "homeFeed" variable wasn't changed at all .

I **debugged** the code to get ensured that no errors occur with api call and the **variable** is changed inside the method **( but not outside it! )**

I am really stuck with that , any help ?

Comment: Why do you use global variables for this anyway? That is really bad practice.

Comment: @marstran I know but in this case ,when i declare it locally ( inside Onresponse method ) , i can't return it since the method is overrided and mustn't return anything

Comment: But there's better ways to capture the result of a network call...

Comment: client.newCall(request).enqueue(...) is asynchronous. You cant call places.execute() and the immediately expect the result in places.GetData(). You should use reactive or callback approach.

Comment: You can use val response = client.newCall(request).execute(), but it needs to be called in non main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `getData()` immediately after making the async request, so it hasn't had a chance to be updated. Asynchronous functions do not immediately return. Some background thread does something (a network request), and in this case calls `onResponse` when the result is returned some time in the future.

It's just like the listener on your button. The code in the listener isn't run immediately, but some time in the future when the user presses it.

Instead of using this member property, your function can take a callback parameter that it invokes when the result is ready:

```
fun execute(resultHandler: (HomeFeed) -> Unit) {
    //... snip ...

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
        // ... snip ...
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val ch = response?.body?.string()
            val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
            resultHandler(gson.fromJson(ch, HomeFeed::class.java))
        }
    })

}
```

Then when you call it, you pass a lambda that will be called when the result is ready:

```
   btn.setOnClickListener {
      val destination = "destination"
      val places = FetchData(destination)
      places.execute { homeFeedData ->
          // Do something with homeFeedData when it arrives
      }
   }
```

Comment: That is the right solution , now what to modify to make execute function return this HomeFeed

Comment: It can’t return it because functions return immediately and it is doing something that takes a while in a background thread. (It could be written to be a blocking call but that will freeze the UI and cause an ANR crash.) You can assign the value to a variable using the callback where I marked “do something with HomeFeed”. This is where you would continue your logic flow of handling the response.

Comment: The issue is that i want to make all handling outside (places.execute{ }) , all handling is based on this homeFeedData, when i assign the value to a var variable,as you mentioned, inside the ".execute" and want to recover it outside , i find the variable unchanged

Comment: Sounds like you are making the same mistake as you originally did. If you check the variable immediately, it hasn't been updated yet. To do what you're describing, you would have to use coroutines, which allow functions to be suspended and then later continue where they left off when some background task is completed. It looks like someone has written a [helper library for OkHttp](https://github.com/gildor/kotlin-coroutines-okhttp) to use coroutines. Coroutines in general are not trivial to learn but can lead to much cleaner code.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-networking-in-2019-retrofit-with-kotlins-coroutines-aefe82c4d777) about using coroutines for networking on Android (I didn't read it so can't vouch for it).